# Why doesn't autofocus="autofocus" work in Mozilla Firefox?

Tags: html5, firefox, forms

```
<INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME="Gw" MAXLENGTH="225" size="42" autofocus="autofocus">
```

If I try this with Google Chrome it works. I just want to highlight a form without `<script>`.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: What version  of Firefox are you using?

Comment: Which Version are you using of Firefox ? In Past firefox did not support autofocus but it is fine and working at my side.... I am using firefox 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work in Firefox 4. But if you're using an older version of Firefox it won't work as the autofocus attribute is new to HTML5 which only gained broad support in Firefox 4..

Answer (score 7):

It's wise to use `autofocus` with a JavaScript fallback for browsers that don't support it. From Mark Pilgrim's [Dive into HTML5 Forms](http://diveintohtml5.org/forms.html):

> What’s that? You say you want your
>   autofocus fields to work in all
>   browsers, not just these fancy-pants
>   HTML5 browsers? You can keep your
>   current autofocus script. Just make
>   two small changes:
>
> 1. Add the autofocus attribute to your HTML markup
> 2. Detect whether the browser supports
>      the autofocus attribute, and only run
>      your own autofocus script if the
>      browser doesn’t support autofocus
>      natively.

```
<form name="f">
  <input id="q" type="text" name="Gw" maxlength="225" size="42" autofocus>
  <script>
    if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input"))) {
      document.getElementById("q").focus();
    }
  </script>
  <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

[Live demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/rhWpc/)

Comment: It's a bad thing I could accept two answers, yours would be the 2 :( :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I try for new some code.
Actually, i use Firefox 34.xx version, but can't still use autofocus.
I Try code above, but didn't work for me, then i try to make own code. i use jquery library.
if you didn' work too, try this code:
HTML

```
<input type="text" name="searchMenu" placeholder="blaa.. blaaa..." id="searchMenu" autofocus focus>


$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#searchMenu").focus();
});
```